# How to get an NSDate from an integer passed in as and id?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, casting, nsdate

This is driving me nuts so I hope someone can help an Objective-C noob figure this out.  Here's the deal:

I'm developing an iPhone app using Titanium Appcelerator and I'm trying to create an add-on module in XCode that will allow me to send an event to the iPhone calendar. What I'd like to do is to calculate the date and time in terms of seconds since Jan 1, 2001 (GMT) and send it directly to calendar without having to mess with the string-to-date stuff that seems always to return the wrong time.  To this point, I've not been able to get the integer into the event date fields, both of which are NSDate types.

Titanium takes arguments from Javascript and compiles it into object code, so I can call my "cal" object like this:

```
var startDate = 316367923;
var endDate = 316367923;    
var results = cal.newEvent(startTime,endTime)
```

. . . and this is how the "cal" object receives that call:

```
-(BOOL)newEvent:(id)args {
    id startDate = [args objectAtIndex:0];
    id endDate = [args objectAtIndex:1];
    ...
```

What I'm hoping to do get these integers into the event object:

```
EKEventStore *eventDB = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *theEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];
...
theEvent.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (int) startDate];
theEvent.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (int) endDate];
```

This compiles with no errors but causes my app to bomb nonetheless, so I'm figuring I've got something missing in my understanding.  Any idea of where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Where does your app crash/what's the specific error?

Comment: Since I wrote this, it turned out that the crash was unrelated -- I was trying to release a pointer that hadn't been allocated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite probably 'args' is an NSArray, hence startDate and endDate are objects, not literals. You probably want to do something like:

```
theEvent.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[startDate intValue]];
```

If e.g. startDate is an NSNumber. Otherwise, check out the Titanium docs to find out the type of numbers passed in.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cause of your crash, but the initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method is expecting an NSTimeInterval (defined as `typedef double NSTimeInterval`) not an integer.

i.e.: Its method signature is:

```
- (id)initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet startDate and endDate are being converted to NSNumber objects instead of ints.  Therefore, try the following lines:

```
theEvent.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (int) [startDate intValue]];
theEvent.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (int) [endDate intValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your crash has anything to do with it but, you might be leaking. The lines:

```
theEvent.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (int) startDate];
theEvent.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (int) endDate];
```

assign an object with retain count 1, if the setter for startDate and EndDate takes ownership of them (I don't know if java will do that or not so I might be wrong) you must store them in a local variable before assigning them to theEvent, so that you can call release afterwards.
so it would look like this:

```
    NSDate *sDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[startDate intValue]];
   theEvent.startDate = sDate;
   [sDate release];
```